# dfp PHP API - Max requests

Tags: php, api, google-dfp

I am using `PHP API` for `DFP` for one of my projects.

Can anyone help me with any information on `maximum requests per minute / hour` that I can make?

I tried Googling but couldn't find any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an official number for the maximum requests you can make per minute or hour.

However reading the docs they do seem to recommend not exceeding more than 2 requests per second:

https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201306/NetworkService.QuotaError#reason